# SQL server database tables are not accessed

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, sql-server-2005, iis

I have created a web-service using asp.NET with SQL Server 2005 database. Then I published it to local IIS, but when I publish it Visual Studio showed me an error stated that:

> the process cannot access the file (path to database) because it is being used by another process.

so, I Detach the database. then I published the web-service. Now, when Browsing my web-service from IIS Manager, and try  to test some methods, an error page appears to say:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Student'.

where *Student* is a table in my database.

my connectionString is:

`<add name="sbms" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Does Detaching the database cause this error? or there are errors in my ConnectionString? I search in Google and didn't find solution.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Detaching the database will cause the second error. The SqlClient can't find the table referenced by your code.

The first error comes from the database being opened in SQL Server in single user mode. Re-attach the database to SQL Server.  Then change the connection settings to multiuser.

[Detailed instructions for setting either single or multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587360/change-to-database-to-online-and-set-db-to-multi-user)

Comment: how to change the connection settings to multiuser?